# how to get logo all the way to the left with css

Tags: css, header

I'm making a header and the logo is not all the way to the left..

This is how my header looks:

[image]

As you can see its not all the way to the left..

This is my header html:

```
<header>
            <ul id="left-nav">
                <li><img class="logo" src="<?= base_url('images/') ?>jongerenkansrijkerlogo.png" alt="Jongeren kansrijker logo"/></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="right-nav">
           <?php if((isset($_SESSION['werknemer_level']) && $_SESSION['werknemer_level'] == 1) || (isset($_SESSION['administrator_level']) && $_SESSION['administrator_level'] == 1)): ?>
            <li> <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Addjongere">Overzicht jongeren</a> </li> 
            <li> <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/Jongeren_activiteiten">Overzicht activiteiten</a> </li> 
            <li> <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/Addwerknemer">Overzicht medewerkers</a> </li> 
            <li> <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/Instituut">Overzicht Instituten</a> </li> 
            <li> <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/index.php/Auth/logout">Uitloggen</a> </li> 
            <?php endif;?>
            </ul>
        </header>
```

I use float: left; but its not all the way to the left
css code:

```
#left-nav{
    float:left;
}

#right-nav{
    float:right;
    margin-top:30px;
}

#right-nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Thanks any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: it has default margin and padding on `ul`. Try adding `#left-nav{ padding:0; }`

Comment: if the ul has a margin left then you need to set that to 0 `margin-left: 0`

Answer (score 3):

A list has a default `padding-left`. Remove that.

```
#left-nav{
    float:left;
    padding: 0; /* <-- add this line */
}
```

Comment: @Jeremy I suggest u better use `*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
` to your css, then you wont have this problem again. Since default padding and margin is diffrent in every browser.

Comment: @LinkinTED depends if you really need it, 3 lines of code take less time then a new file request. (if you want the site to be as fast as possible)